# No encuentro el id de mi gridView en el código de mi vista

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CVE_DOC" HeaderText="CLAVE DOCUMENTO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CVE_CLPV" HeaderText="CLAVE PRECIO VENTA" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ESTATUS" HeaderText="ESTATUS" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SU_REFER" HeaderText="REFERENCIA" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FECHA_DOC" HeaderText="FECHA DOCUMENTO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FECHA_REC" HeaderText="FECHA RECIBIDO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FECHA_PAG" HeaderText="FECHA PAGADO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CAN_TOT" HeaderText="CANTIDAD TOTAL" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="IMP_TOT1" HeaderText="IMPORTE TOTAL 1" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="IMP_TOT2" HeaderText="IMPORTE TOTAL 2" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="IMP_TOT3" HeaderText="IMPORTE TOTAL 3" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="IMP_TOT4" HeaderText="IMPORTE TOTAL 4" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DES_TOT" HeaderText="DESCUENTO TOTAL" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DES_FIN" HeaderText="DESCUENTO FINAL" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TOT_IND" HeaderText="TOTAL INDIVIDUAL" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OBS_COND" HeaderText="OBSERVACIONES" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CVE_OBS" HeaderText="CLAVE OBSERVACION" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_ALMA" HeaderText="NUMERO ALMACÉN" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ACT_CXP" HeaderText="ACTA CXP" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ACT_COI" HeaderText="ACTA COI" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ENLAZADO" HeaderText="ENLAZADO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TIP_DOC_E" HeaderText="TIPO DOCUMENTO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_MONED" HeaderText="NUMERO MONEDA" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TIPCAMB" HeaderText="TIPO DE CAMBIO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_PAGOS" HeaderText="NUMERO DE PAGOS" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FECHAELAB" HeaderText="FECHA ELABORACIÓN" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SERIE" HeaderText="SERIE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FOLIO" HeaderText="FOLIO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CTLPOL" HeaderText="PUNTO DE CONTROL" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ESCFD" HeaderText="ESCFD" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CONTADO" HeaderText="CONTADO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="IMPORTE" HeaderText="IMPORTE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TIP_DOC_ANT" HeaderText="TIPO DOCUMENTO ANTERIOR" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC_ANT" HeaderText="DOCUMENTO ANTERIOR" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TIP_DOC_SIG" HeaderText="TIPO DOCUMENTO SIGUIENTE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC_SIG" HeaderText="DOCUMENTO SIGUIENTE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FORMAENVIO" HeaderText="FORMA ENVIO" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="METODODEPAGO" HeaderText="METODO DE PAGO" /> 
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

El problema que tengo es que en mi código al querer mandarle el modelo me dice que no encuentra el objeto y me da error. Tal vez lo que me falta es agregar el grid en alguna parte pero buscando en internet lo hacen de la misma forma en que lo hago yo, sólo con el id supuestamente debería reconocerlo. ¿Será que me estoy saltando algo?

Adjunto imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existen 3 archivos: El primero es la "Vista" y luego tienes 2 archivos que son el `code behind` (por eso la clases llevan `partial`). El primer archivo es el que tu editas y el otro lo edita visual studio, este archivo es el que permite que tu puedas llamar a un objeto por su Id y no tener que buscarlo como se hace, por ejemplo, en java. Posiblemente tu tengas este archivo corrupto, esto recuerdo que pasaba cuando este archivo estaba abierto y editabas la vista, lo más fácil es copiar todo y luego borrar los 3 archivos y volver a crearlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probaré con eso!